# MySql - view out params of stored procedure when it selects from table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, information-schema

I have stored procedure:

```sql
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE prcGetFemaleUsers()
begin
    select firstName, lastName
    from tblUser
    where gender = 'female';
end //
DELIMITER ;
```

How can I get types that this procedure returns?
I'd expect to get something like:

```sql
firstname varchar(50)
lastname varchar(50)
```

I know there is this:

```sql
SELECT ROUTINE_DEFINITION
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE ROUTINE_SCHEMA = 'yourdb' 
  AND ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'
  AND ROUTINE_NAME = "procedurename";
```

... and a better version of this:

```sql
SELECT param_list, returns
FROM mysql.proc
WHERE db='yourdb'
  AND type='PROCEDURE'
  AND name='procedurename';
```

... but none of them give me desired results.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why the *better version* doesn't work for you?

Comment: @oNare `returns` column is empty.

Comment: Can you query `mysql.db`? If not, you don't have privileges to access it.

Comment: @oNare I can, I run as admin.

Comment: `returns` column will be for `type=FUNCTION` only. You might try using c/php/java connector - they have some methods for accessing result metadata (column names and types etc.) which are not accessible using sql statements. (for instance in php you can get these http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field-direct.php#refsect1-mysqli-result.fetch-field-direct-returnvalues )